# Measure and Integration theory based on intuitionism

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, axiom-of-choice, intuitionistic-logic

Measure and integration theory uses the axiom of choice extensively, for example the idea behind σ-algebra is that there are non-measurable sets (in the sense of lebesgue) like [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set#cite_note-2), but on the other hand Solovay has prove that their exist model of ZF without axiom of choice in which every set of reals is measurable.

This is why I ask myself  if you know if there are courses in measure theory and integration that do not use the axiom of choice or even better that are based on intuitionism ?

Sorry if my question is not very clear, I am not an expert in intuitionism, just a bit curious about it.

Comment: To some extent, you can find a lot in Fremlin's Measure Theory vol. 5

Comment: Just a minor hint: The idea of a sigma algebra doesn't need the axiom of choice and it is not solely there to avoid trouble with non-measurable sets. For example in probability theory a sigma algebra is often interpreted as a body of information not just a set of "reasonable" sets.

Comment: One avenue to look is [Errett Bishop's 1967 book **Foundations of Constructive Analysis** and the work derived from it](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bishop+constructive+analysis&filter=0). See also the results of the google search [Bishop + constructive + analysis + "measure theory"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bishop+constructive+analysis+%22measure+theory%22&filter=0).